# Java Excel Manipulation

Tags: java, mysql, excel

Hello i a am curently trying to read an excel file and manipulate it as a database. I wrote the following code whitch i supposed to fetch the first row of the datasheet and print it

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class ExcelReader { 

   public static void main( String [] args ) {

    Connection c = null; Statement stmnt = null;

    try
    {
        Class.forName( "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" );

        //using DSN connection. Here qa is the name of DSN
        //c = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:qa", "", "" );

        //using DSN-less connection
        c = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=C:/Users/Μιχάλης/Documents/mike1.xls");


        stmnt = c.createStatement();
        String query = "select * from [Ledis$] ;";
        ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery( query );
        while( rs.next() )
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));

        }
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        //System.err.println( e );
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            stmnt.close();
            c.close();
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            System.err.println( e );
        }
    }
  }
}
```

When i execute the upper code i get the following print out

```
90-02-00-0000-2000
90-02-00-0000-2400
90-02-00-0000-2500
90-02-00-0000
90-02-00
90-02
90-06-00-0000-6000
90-06-00-0000-6100
90-06-00-0000-6200
90-06-00-0000-6300
90-06-00-0000-6400
90-06-00-0000-6500
90-06-00-0000-6600
90-06-00-0000
90-06-00
90-06
null
```

The problem is that in the last column the price that was supposed to be printed is 90 instead of null.

Does anybody have any idea of what is happening;

Comment: Could you make sure the last rows in your excel file actually contain nothing (even if you had data entered and now deleted it, sometimes there are spaces or LF/CR or something). Select the 5 rows beneath your data (using the numbers in front of them) and delete these rows, and see what the output of your program is now.

Comment: I tried that and still nothing .... Should i upload you the file?

Comment: Are you sure null is not coming from System.err.println( e );?

Comment: Not sure... How can i check it;

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java however all the values printed are stored as strings in Excel where as 90 would be stored as a number. I'd be surprised if that was the issue however.

Comment: if it doesn't have a hyphen it will be stored as number ... resulting in the problem as java expects a string, not an integer because of  `System.out.println(rs.getString(1));`